# Output values differ between R and Python?

Tags: python, r, debugging, numpy, statistics

Perhaps I am doing something wrong while [z-normalizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score) my array. Can someone take a look at this and suggest what's going on?

**In R:**

```
> data <- c(2.02, 2.33, 2.99, 6.85, 9.20, 8.80, 7.50, 6.00, 5.85, 3.85, 4.85, 3.85, 2.22, 1.45, 1.34)
> data.mean <- mean(data)
> data.sd <- sqrt(var(data))
> data.norm <- (data - data.mean) / data.sd
> print(data.norm)
 [1] -0.9796808 -0.8622706 -0.6123005  0.8496459  1.7396910  1.5881940  1.0958286  0.5277147  0.4709033 -0.2865819
[11]  0.0921607 -0.2865819 -0.9039323 -1.1955641 -1.2372258
```

**In Python using numpy:**

```
>>> import string
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy.stats import norm
>>> data = np.array([np.array([2.02, 2.33, 2.99, 6.85, 9.20, 8.80, 7.50, 6.00, 5.85, 3.85, 4.85, 3.85, 2.22, 1.45, 1.34])])
>>> data -= np.split(np.mean(data, axis=1), data.shape[0])
>>> data *= np.split(1.0/data.std(axis=1), data.shape[0])
>>> print data

[[-1.01406602 -0.89253491 -0.63379126  0.87946705  1.80075126  1.64393692
   1.13429034  0.54623659  0.48743122 -0.29664045  0.09539539 -0.29664045
  -0.93565885 -1.23752644 -1.28065039]]
```

Am I using `numpy` incorrectly?

Comment: Why are you setting `data` as an np.array inside another np.array?

Comment: @HughBothwell: Oh... I did not notice that. This was simplified from a bigger piece of code where data was an array of arrays.

Comment: Just for the record, in R you can normalize using `data.norm <- scale(data, center=TRUE, scale=TRUE)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe that your NumPy result is correct.  I would do the normalization in a simpler way, though:

```
>>> data = np.array([2.02, 2.33, 2.99, 6.85, 9.20, 8.80, 7.50, 6.00, 5.85, 3.85, 4.85, 3.85, 2.22, 1.45, 1.34])
>>> data -= data.mean()
>>> data /= data.std()
>>> data
array([-1.01406602, -0.89253491, -0.63379126,  0.87946705,  1.80075126,
        1.64393692,  1.13429034,  0.54623659,  0.48743122, -0.29664045,
        0.09539539, -0.29664045, -0.93565885, -1.23752644, -1.28065039])
```

The difference between your two results lies in the normalization: with `r` as the R result:

```
>>> r / data
array([ 0.96609173,  0.96609173,  0.96609173,  0.96609179,  0.96609179, 0.96609181,  0.9660918 ,  0.96609181,
        0.96609179,  0.96609179,        0.9660918 ,  0.96609179,  0.96609175,  0.96609176,  0.96609177])
```

Thus, your two results are mostly simply proportional to each other.  You may therefore want to compare the standard deviations obtained with R and with Python.

**PS**: Now that I am thinking of it, it may be that the variance in NumPy and in R is not defined in the same way: for `N` elements, some tools normalize with `N-1` instead of `N`, when calculating the variance. You may want to check this.

**PPS**: **Here is the reason** for the discrepancy: the difference in factors comes from two different normalization conventions: the observed factor is simply sqrt(14/15) = 0.9660917… (because the data has 15 elements). Thus, in order to obtain in R the same result as in Python, you need to divide the R result by this factor.

Comment: +1 Thank  for confirming. Is this approach extensible for the case when data has multiple arrays inside (like in my question but multiple array elements)? Also, any idea why the result from `R` is different?

Comment: @Legend I can confirm that R uses n-1 as a denominator, and was just thinking that might be the difference. As a stats guy, I'm actually a little shocked that numpy would use n by default, but I'm sure someone's saying just the opposite about R right now.

Comment: @Legend: The `axis=1` parameter that you used in the answer is the way to go, if you have arrays inside arrays.

Comment: @joran: While I fully respect R's convention, I like NumPy's `N` convention: it allows one to interpret the standard deviation as the spread of the values; the `N` convention gives a relevant result even for a single value (0 spread), where a `N-1` denominator would give an undefined result.

Comment: @EOL Funny, I think the exact opposite is more natural. With only one value, there is an absence of information about variation from the mean, so the sd _should_ be undefined. This is by far the silliest disagreement I've had in a while, though.

Comment: @joran: I may be biased, but I prefer the `N` convention ([ba-dum-bum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ba-dum-bum)).

Answer (score 20):

The reason you're getting different results has to do with how the standard deviation/variance is calculated.  R calculates using denominator `N-1`, while numpy calculates using denominator `N`.  You can get a numpy result equal to the R result by using `data.std(ddof=1)`, which tells numpy to use `N-1` as the denominator when calculating the variance.

Comment: +1 for `ddof=1`, which is simpler than putting the correcting factor by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Dividing by N-1, as in R, gives an [unbiased estimate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbiased_estimation_of_standard_deviation) of the variance; generally speaking one desires an unbiased estimate. The Numpy implementation is incorrect.