# Standard deviation different in R and Python

Tags: python, r, statistics

I am trying to learn Python, and I am learning statistics as well, so I wanted to see if I can make my own function to get the **mean**, **variance** and finally a **standard deviation** of a dataset.

So I created the function for the variance using `map()` and `lambda` but I got the wrong result, when I was comparing it with R that I had running on another screen. I found out that if I used the `numpy` library in python, I would get the exact same values as the ones I got in my home made function.

### Python

```py
females = [2474,2547,2830,3219,3429,3448,3677,3872,4001,4116]
males   = [2844,2863,2963,3239,3379,3449,3582,3926,4151,4356]
def std_deviance(data):
    mean        = sum(data)/len(data)
    variance    = sum(list(map(lambda x: (x-mean)**2,data)))/len(data)
    return      variance**(1/2)
print('Females:\t', std_deviance(females))
# Females:     557.1610269930948
print('Males:\t\t',std_deviance(males))
# Males:       504.81913592889873
```

### R

```
females <- c(2474,2574,2830,3219,3429,3448,3677,3872,4001,4116)
males   <- c(2844,2863,2963,3239,3379,3449,3582,3926,4151,4356)
sd(females)
[1] 583.1874
sd(males)
[1] 532.1261
```

### Python with numpy

```
from numpy import std
females = [2474,2547,2830,3219,3429,3448,3677,3872,4001,4116]
males   = [2844,2863,2963,3239,3379,3449,3582,3926,4151,4356]
print('Females:\t', std(females))
# Females:   557.1610269930948
print('Males:\t\t',std(males))
# Males:     504.81913592889873
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.

Comment: The search term you need is the correct spelling, "variance", the square of the standard deviation.

Comment: Most of all, why are you writing your own formulae instead of using the ones readily available in various packages?

Comment: @Prune 
1. I will give some data as well. sorry.
2. I will edit the question now
3. Because I am trying to learn python not statistics :)

Comment: @Prune please check my code again, and vote to reopen, or let me know how to clarify.

Comment: Where do the intermediate results of your calculation differ from the expected ones?  You first need to break this down into sub-expressions and check where you went wrong, no?

Comment: check my code now, I broke it up into some pieces. What do you think?

Comment: I just ran the code and compared it to the function `var()` in numpy. and it seem that it returns the same value, as my function. So maybe I just did something wrong in R. Sorry for the inconvenience .

Comment: This is why I asked for the debugging work.  Since this is solved due to an error outside the question, I suggest that you delete the question, as it's not useful to posterity.  :-)

Comment: Should I post a new question with the content of the question as it is now then?

Comment: That's a good idea.  Also, make a *minimal* test case: fewer, simpler values.  We should be able to check the math in our heads.  Again, break up your calculation into sub-expressions and trace the results.  Finally,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a typographical error.  (The second element of the `females` vector is 2547 in your Python example, 2574 in your R example.) Once you correct that, this question is a duplicate of [Output values differ between R and Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11236951/output-values-differ-between-r-and-python)